# NDSolve with Piecewise function consideres some value inside Piecewise as Indeterninate

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, piecewise

I'm solving a PDE, with one coefficient being piecewise. The issue appears to be that  `NDSolve` somehow consideres piesewise boundary as `Indeterminate`:

[image]

How do I tell Mathematica that there are no `Indeterminate` points in that region?

Here's the code:

```
piecewise = {{1.`, 0.` < x <= 7.022095903128504`},
             {1.`, 7.022095903128504` < x <= 14.044191806257007`},
             {0.`, 14.044191806257007` < x <= 22.85854978939524`},
             {1.`, 22.85854978939524` < x <= 29.880645692523743`},
             {1.`, 29.880645692523743` < x <= 36.902741595652245`},
             {0.`, 36.902741595652245` < x <= 45.71709957879048`}};

\[Delta]n[x_] := Piecewise[piecewise, 0.];

NDSolveValue[{
  z''[x] \[Delta]n[x] + z[x] == 0,
  z[0] == 0,
  z[45.71709957879049] == 0
  },
 z,
 {x, 0, 45.71709957879049}
 , Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}
 ];
```

Basically, I have a range `[0,45.71709957879049]` which is packed by molecules with lengths 7.0221 and 8.81436, in the following order: 1,1,0,1,1,0. Here 1 being molecule with length 7.0221 and 0 is a molecule with length 8.81436.

So I create a piecewise function like above, and inserted that to an differential equation. However I can't convince mathematica that the whole space of the range is occupited either by one molecule or by the another.

Comment: Firstly, please post code instead of the image, so that we can run the code ourselves. Secondly, look at the expression below the red arrow: $135851173/5943123=22.8585$, and there is a strong inequality $<$.

Comment: @Adobe Do you try to solve equation `z[x]==0` with using FEM?

Comment: @AlexTrounev it is differential equation, so I'm trying to solve it with `NDSolve`. As some coefficients of the equation are discontinuous I try to use FEM.

Comment: @Domen I tried all sorts of inequalities - I get the same error. I've added the code.

Comment: @Adobe Please, pay attention that `z=0` is a solution of your problem. What is the reason to use FEM to compute solution of equation `z[x]==0` in a region where $\delta n(x)=0$?